# How to pass a node.js Buffer to a function which expects a Stream?

Tags: node.js, tar

I have a Buffer with tar contents and I would like to parse this with [tar](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar) node.js package, but all examples of use of this package are using .pipe() and streams - how can I pass buffer to tar package?

I get Buffer from [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams have a standard API, so you can just use `write` and `end` directly instead of using `pipe`.

```
var data = ... // Buffer
var parser = tar.Parse();

// Bind whatever handlers you would normally bind
parser.on('entry', function(e){
});

// Write the data into the parser, which will parse it and trigger your event handlers
parser.end(data);
```